# Add Line to xyGraph using A chart Engine in android

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I'm using a chart engine to plot graph. I drawn graph .But now i want to add one line to graph while plotting values to graph. Can anyone suggest me how to get this?
I searched but i didn't get any resources to do this.

I want to add line like this . The output needed should be like the one shown in the picture.
.After reaching end of the view that line should come from the starting of the view[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra series that just contain 2 points that would define such a line.